# Mudando cor da ActionBar no Style

Tags: android, actionbar

Estou estudando para desenvolver aplicações Android, estou fazendo um App, mas não consigo mudar a cor da minha ActionBar. Estou desenvolvendo para Android KitKat.

Esse é meu style.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#009933</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

No meu manifest está o tema 'AppTheme'.

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Você está utilizando o AppCompat?

Answer (score 4):

Eu estava quebrando a cabeça, mas está resolvido. Se estiverem usando a API 11 ou superior, basta acrescentar, no método OnCreate no arquivo .java da Atividade Principal do seu app (MainActivity.java, por exemplo):

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#cor")));
```

Claro, lembrem-se de mudar a #cor para o código hexadecimal da cor que desejarem.

Se não funcionar, tentem essa variação:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#cor")));
```

No meu caso, só funcionou a primeira forma. É o mais fácil de mudar sem precisar mexer ou criar arquivos na pasta values

Comment: Onde eu coloco este código?

Answer (score -2):

Caso esteja utilizando a AppCompat Material Design, você definirá pela cor primária:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_grey_900</item>
</style>
```

Caso contrário (APIs anteriores), use no atributo parent da sua ActionBar o estilo vindo de Widget, por exemplo:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
```